# Is there any way to allow me access the .NET TreeView control in another application?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check some internal property which is not exposed by UIA, e.g. tag, nodes property.

I have a way to inject my procedure into the target application process, and this procedure can access the target Treeview control since they are in same process (using Control.Fromhandle(handle)); but the problem is that I have no effective way to return the whole Treeview control copy.

I can use IPC to return the control through proxy; but this is only useful to access its basic type property, e.g. name ..; for "nodes" property, I cannot access.

Has anybody tried to access all the properties of a control across different applications?

I am sure the QTP has the capability.

Comment: What do the acronyms used in your question mean? What is UIA, IPC, and QTP?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass the TreeView control - i.e. make a UserControl which inherits the TreeView control.

Then you can add methods for the internal content manipulation and call this methods by IPC e.g.